# where has sun mysql database manager gone?

Tags: mysql, database, frontend

If I recall correctly, there where at least to desktop programas from sun which were very useful for handling mysql databases...

Now, all I can find is some mysql workbench which is only useful for designing data...

Both programs I'm talking about allowed you to manage servers, create database, create tables, index, perform querys, edit data, etc...

unfortunately I don't even recall their names...

Any idea where I can find them?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)?

They represent a set of applications for the administration of MySQL database servers, and for building and manipulating the data within MySQL databases.